# PHP: Sort Object Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, object

So lets say I have this:

```
<?php
    $obj=(object)array("this"=>"that","and"=>"the","other"=>(object)array("layers"=>"make","things"=>"more","fun"=>(object)array("every"=>"time","foo"=>"bar")));
    var_dump($obj);
?>
```

which outputs this:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
  ["this"]=>
  string(4) "that"
  ["and"]=>
  string(3) "the"
  ["other"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["layers"]=>
    string(4) "make"
    ["things"]=>
    string(4) "more"
    ["fun"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["every"]=>
      string(4) "time"
      ["foo"]=>
      string(3) "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

But I want it sorted by keys like this preferably without having to make a array or ever layer of keys and sort it and rebuilding the object in order
like this:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
  ["and"]=>
  string(4) "the"
  ["other"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["fun"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["every"]=>
      string(4) "time"
      ["foo"]=>
      string(3) "bar"
    }
    ["layers"]=>
    string(4) "make"
    ["things"]=>
    string(4) "more"
  }
  ["this"]=>
  string(3) "that"
}
```

I think web browsers will do this sorting automatically as I seem to recall having to workaround this when I had a custom sorting feature I made break some years ago in firfox, so I could just `json_encode` it and let the client handle this part so the browser will just sort it with no sorting effort on my part

Comment: No: https://pastebin.com/PzMgxWNV

Comment: You need to do it *before* casting your array into an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just sort and return the sorted array
function array_ksort(array $array) {
    ksort($array);
    return $array;
}

$obj = (object) array_ksort(array_map(function($value) { return !is_object($value) ? $value : (object) array_ksort((array) $value);}, $obj));
```

Check result here : https://3v4l.org/2hZsB

Comment: Did I try it wrong? https://pastebin.com/0jGDeNA9 (tested in terminal)

Comment: you had to cast `$obj` in the second `var_dump` here is the right version :
`<?php
function array_ksort(array $array) {
    ksort($array);
    return $array;
}
 $obj=(object)array("this"=>"that","and"=>"the","other"=>(object)array("layers"=>"make","things"=>"more","fun"=>(object)array("every"=>"time","foo"=>"bar")));
 var_dump($obj);
 $obj = (object) array_ksort(array_map(function($value) { return !is_object($value) ? $value : (object) array_ksort((array) $value);}, (array) $obj));
 var_dump($obj);
?>`

Comment: Thanks, that looks to work; though I rewrote the code in JS already and still had to sort it...

Comment: Correction seems to not sort 100% properly with real data at least in layer 3, this was how i did it: https://pastebin.com/gVqQeQbx